# Django: Preventing automatic deletion of model data after each test

Tags: django, django-testing

I've simplified my code to show the effect here.

```
class AccountTests(APITestCase):
    def test_post_account(self):
        """
        Ensure we can create a new account object
        """

        # code that adds one user object and one signup confirmation object
        ...
        ...

        # test we have one user and one confirmation code
        # THIS PASSES OK.   
        self.assertEqual(User.objects.count(), 1)
        self.assertEqual(SignupConfirmationCode.objects.count(), )


    def test_post_confirmation_code(self):
        """
        test sending confirmation code for an account just created
        """
        # THIS FAILS
        self.assertEqual(User.objects.count(), 1)
        self.assertEqual(SignupConfirmationCode.objects.count(), 1)
```

I know `test_post_account` is running first and passes OK. `test_post_confirmation_code` is running second and asserts on account of the `User` and `SignupConfirmataionCode` "magically" losing their content between the two test methods.

How do I prevent the disappearance of data between the time the first test ends and the second begins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't. You set up your tests so that they each create the data they need.

The code in your first test that sets up the user and the confirmation should be extracted into the `setUp` method, which runs before each test.

Comment: Understood. In a way it makes sense. helps avoid an order chaos and preserves test independence.